# Change text in reusable pipeline in DKPro

Tags: java, uima, dkpro-core

[This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988426/reusable-version-of-dkpro-core-pipeline/36997794) describes how to reuse a pipeline in dkpro but if I only create one JCas and then try to change the text then I get the exception

`org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException: Data for Sofa feature setLocalSofaData() has already been set.`

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sofa data in the CAS can only be set once. It cannot be modified after it has been set.

In order to re-use a CAS, call the `reset()` method on it. This clears all annotations and allows you to set the sofa/text again.

To build a CAS incrementally, a common strategies is to add annotations to the CAS while adding text to a string buffer and setting the text only at the end of the process.

An uimaFIT-based example could look something like this:

```
Strings[] texts = {
    "Hello world.",
    "This is a test." };

// Create empty CAS/JCas initialized using uimaFIT typesystem auto-detection
JCas jcas = JCasFactory.createJCas();

// Instantiate some analysis engine
AnalysisEngine engine = AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngine(...);

// Process texts re-using the previously created CAS/JCas instance
for (String t : texts) {
    jcas.reset();
    jcas.setDocumentText(t);
    jcas.setDocumentLanguage("en");
    engine.process(jcas);
}

engine.collectionProcessComplete();
engine.destroy();
```

*Disclosure: I am working on the Apache UIMA project.*

Comment: Do you still get the performance benefits of not having to reload all models etc. (address is the referenced question) by doing it this way?

Comment: If you instantiate actual components using e.g. the uimaFIT `AnalysisEngine engine = AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngine(...)` calls, then typically models/resources are loaded only once (on instantiation or on the first processed document). Process CASes using `engine.process(cas);`.